# Android drawable custom shape stroke multiple items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, drawable, android-tabs

I have a custom shape I am trying to create to be the background of a tabview.

This is the desired result:

[image: end result]

I am trying to create the background of the active tab with this step.

I have the background as a different color so I can see what is doing what for now.

This is what I have so far:
[image: This is what I have so far]

But when trying to add a stroke to the shape, this happens:
[image: Trying to add the stroke]

Does anyone have an idea on how I can get to the result I stated above (with the corner radius' and stroke)?

Here is the drawable code (`drawable/tab_active.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Colored rectangle-->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="100dp"
                android:height="40dp" />
            <solid android:color="#13a89e" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/warmGray" />
            <corners
                android:topRightRadius="0dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="32dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="32dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- This rectangle for the left side -->
    <item
        android:right="100dp"
        android:left="-100dp"
        android:top="-100dp"
        android:bottom="-100dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#13a89e" />
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="@color/warmGray" />
                <padding
                    android:bottom="0dip"
                    android:left="0dip"
                    android:right="0dip"
                    android:top="0dip" />

                <corners
                    android:topRightRadius="0dp"
                    android:topLeftRadius="32dp"
                    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
                    android:bottomRightRadius="32dp" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

    <!-- This rectangle for the right side -->
    <item
        android:right="-100dp"
        android:left="100dp"
        android:top="-100dp"
        android:bottom="-100dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="@color/warmGray" />

                <corners
                    android:topRightRadius="32dp"
                    android:topLeftRadius="32dp"
                    android:bottomLeftRadius="32dp"
                    android:bottomRightRadius="32dp" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And then I call it using:

```
<View
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_active"
    android:scaleY="-1" />
```